# Visual Studio Online: Get built code to own server

Tags: web-deployment, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, build-definition

What kind of software is needed to get the **results from builds on Visual Studio Online to your own server**, running IIS? This server would **not be on Azure**.

After setting up a `Build Definition` one can, either through the Visual Studio IDE itself or on Visual Studio Online, queue builds that have the field "*Drop folder for this build*" automatically set and locked to "*Copy drop to server*". How do I get access to this "Drop folder" or duplicate its content on our own server?

Comment: Where is your own server located ? In azure, on prem ?

Comment: On-prem. I'll update the question.

Comment: If the server is on prem, you have two options: 1. Create a on-prem the buildserver and use webdeploy from the builderver. 2. build on VSO and retrieve the binaries/artifacts to on-prem using deploy logic on-prem. Release management can't be coupled (at this moment) to vso, so it would be a more batch type solution like octopus deploy or scripts.

Comment: @RolfHuisman Could you link to some more concrete info regarding option 2?

Comment: It boils down to downloading the binaries from VSO (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a00f0808-d2cb-465c-a908-e4673d6a2d55/copying-files-to-a-static-drop-directory-tfs-hosted-build-service?forum=TFService), and then deploy it internaly using tooling which runs on prem.

Comment: You could use http://chocolatey.org/packages/TfsDropDownloader to download the drop from VSO as well.